# How can i add an item to this kind of array in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, variables, delphi

I have a variable called apps which I think is a dynamic array:

```
  apps2      = array of app3;

  app3 = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fname_: appNameType;
    Fid: appIdType;
  published
    property name_: appNameType  Index (IS_UNQL) read Fname_ write Fname_;
    property id:    appIdType    Index (IS_UNQL) read Fid write Fid;
  end;
```

I have a class inititateTechnicalRegistration and I must pass some value to its apps property. How can i do it?

```
initiateTechnicalRegistration_Type = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FpartnerName: partnerNameType;
    FpartnerOrganizationIdentifier: partnerOrganizationIdentifierType;
    Fapps: apps2;
    Fapps_Specified: boolean;
    Fdescription: descriptionType;
    Fdescription_Specified: boolean;
    FcontactEmail: contactEmailType;
    FrequestedRole: Array_Of_roleType;
    FpublicKey: string;
    FpartnerAddress: partnerAddressType;
    FpartnerAddress_Specified: boolean;
    FpartnerURL: partnerURLType;
    FpartnerURL_Specified: boolean;
    procedure Setapps(Index: Integer; const Aapps2: apps2);
    function  apps_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setdescription(Index: Integer; const AdescriptionType: descriptionType);
    function  description_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetpartnerAddress(Index: Integer; const ApartnerAddressType: partnerAddressType);
    function  partnerAddress_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetpartnerURL(Index: Integer; const ApartnerURLType: partnerURLType);
    function  partnerURL_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property partnerName:                   partnerNameType                    Index (IS_UNQL) read FpartnerName write FpartnerName;
    property partnerOrganizationIdentifier: partnerOrganizationIdentifierType  Index (IS_UNQL) read FpartnerOrganizationIdentifier write FpartnerOrganizationIdentifier;
    property apps:                          apps2                              Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNQL) read Fapps write Setapps stored apps_Specified;
    property description:                   descriptionType                    Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNQL) read Fdescription write Setdescription stored description_Specified;
    property contactEmail:                  contactEmailType                   Index (IS_UNQL) read FcontactEmail write FcontactEmail;
    property requestedRole:                 Array_Of_roleType                  Index (IS_UNBD or IS_UNQL) read FrequestedRole write FrequestedRole;
    property publicKey:                     string                             Index (IS_UNQL) read FpublicKey write FpublicKey;
    property partnerAddress:                partnerAddressType                 Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNQL) read FpartnerAddress write SetpartnerAddress stored partnerAddress_Specified;
    property partnerURL:                    partnerURLType                     Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNQL) read FpartnerURL write SetpartnerURL stored partnerURL_Specified;
  end;

  initiateTechnicalRegistration = class(initiateTechnicalRegistration_Type)
  private
  published
  end;
```

So I want to pass some values to this from some TEdit in runtime or some other way possible, but I have never worked before with these kind of variables, how can I do it?

initiateTechnicalRegistration1.apps :=

Comment: Does your code compile without the line assigning a value to property apps? You should write your code using usual notation. For example, all types should begin with uppercase T. Example: TApps2 = array of TApps3;

Comment: Yes, it does compile without that line

Comment: There is not even a single warning? Not sure you can have a dynamic array as a published property. Which error do you get while assigning the property as with any other type?

Comment: I get the error 'Incompatible types'

Comment: Please show the line you write. I tested the code you show (Well something much simpler but same data types) and it works. I guess you assign something of a different type! You can only assign a variable of type apps2.

Comment: Maybe you want to add an item in the apps property and try to assign an app3 which you can't. To add an item to the array, you must create a method not a property. It is possible to do it with a property but it must be of type apps3 then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i corrected it, now it works

Comment: The good use of stackoverflow is to give an answer to the question. Saying thanks it works doesn't help anyone. I guess it is my last comment which gave you the solution. Please confirm that what you wanted is to add an item to the array (Then you asked the wrong question in the first place).

Comment: One more note: You should learn how to write Delphi program. I mean how to name variables, types, classes, functions,... and how to layout the code so that it is best readable by anyone. I suggest you use this convention: http://wiki.overbyte.be/arch/IcsMidwareCodingStyle.pdf

Comment: Yeah, i wanted to add an item to the array

Comment: Add created an answer, please approve it is that fits your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here after the code for a method to add an item to the Apps array:

```
// Function return the index allocated in the array
function TForm1.AddApp(Value: App3): Integer;
begin
    Result := Length(FApps);
    SetLength(FApps, Result + 1);
    FApps[Result] := Value;
end;
```